# Construct a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I try to construct a homomorphism 
$$\mathbb{Z}[x]  \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[D_p]$$
which is surjective and where $D_p$ is the dihedral group, $\mathbb{Z}[D_p]$ a monoidring . My problem is that $D_p$ has two generators. For groups with one generator I can make it.

Thank you very much

Comment: Maybe I better add the motivation for the question: I am looking for isomorphisms like $\mathbb{Z}[x](X^p-1) \cong \mathbb{Z}[C_p]$ for other than cyclic groups.

Comment: What kind of homomorphism are you looking for ? Note that there couldn't be a surjective ring homomorphism, since $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is commutative, but $\mathbb{Z}[D_p]$ isn't.

Comment: ... But $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[D_p]$ are isomorphic as additive abelian groups (since as such either is free abelian  of countably infinite rank).

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding you question but there can be no surjective morphism from a monoid with one generator a monoid that requires two generators since this would give you a surjective moprhism from a free monoid on one generator to free monoid on two generators. It should be obvious that such a morphism doesn't exist. Therefore, in general, $\mathbb Z [x]$ can surjectively map only into $\mathbb Z[C_p]$, right?

Comment: I would have needed a ringhomomorphism. So there is also no isomorphism for $D_p$ like in my first comment?

Comment: No, there isn't as explained in my first comment.

Comment: ok, thank you. Do you know another way to describe indecomposable modules in $\mathbb{Z}_q \oplus_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z}[D_p]$?

Comment: Over which ring are you looking for indecomposables ?

Comment: Over $\mathbb{Z}_q[G]$, $q$ prime. I thought of writing first $\mathbb{Z}_q[G] \cong \mathbb{Z}_q \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z}[D_p]$ and than look at the second factor.

Comment: Are $\mathbb{Z}_q$ the q-adic numbers or the resuide class ring $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: It are the q-adic numbers

Comment: Ok, so you are looking for indecomposable $\mathbb{Z}_q[D_p]$-modules where $p,q$ are primes and $\mathbb{Z}_q$ are the q-adic numbers ? I would suggest that you post this as a new question.

Comment: Ok, than I will post it in a new question as this approach does not work.